# adb missing in marshmallow device

Tags: android, adb

Basically, I am trying to use

> adb backup -all -f /sdcard/some_folder/some_file_name.ab

ques 1. why adb is removed in marshmallow devices.
ques 2. what is the worked around for using adb related commands in devices with 6.0 and greater versions.
I am trying to fire adb command from terminal inside an android device [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142533/run-adb-command-inside-the-terminal-emulator-or-programmatically-without-root)

1. Marshmallow device **not showing** adb file in /system/bin
   [image: Marshmallow device not showing adb file in /system/bin]
2. JellyBean device **showing** adb file in /system/bin
   [image: Jelly Bean device having adb file in /system/bin]

Comment: what possessed you to bring that AE discussion over to SO?